# Searching for mails received on Saturdays in Gmail

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, gmail-filters

I need to get the list of emails sent on a day of the week by a service. Is that possible to find in Gmail? Such as 'only Saturday' emails or 'Sunday & Wednesday' emails?

Or any email client supports this?

Comment: what is the range?

Comment: Within last 3 years at max.

Comment: that's a big range... if it would be something over 1 year it could be done internally in Gmail by using epoch time, so I guess you will need to scrape your Gmail with some 3rd party app and filter it out. for example with Google Sheets

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a working solution. So I guess, there is no straight forward support from gmail filters!?

Comment: filter is limited to 1894 characters where inputting 1day costs approx. 40 characters multiplied by 46 days equals around 10.5 months << so that's the max range you can filter in Gmail internally

Comment: Is this extracting every Saturday in a year to epoch time (10 char start + 10 char end per day) and providing it as list of dates to filter? Can you please share some snippet for 1 month/6 month range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I built you generator for a string. Enter range, select a day of the week and copy the string from cell **C7** into Gmail's search...

[image: 0]

### **[spreadsheet generator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14iFsM-j6BonNUzTttiA8sYrmQQvc4pcDIGyKA8UrcQk/copy)**

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! I'll reiterate multiple times to get the data.